# Node.js+socket.io “RangeError: maximum call stack size exceeded”

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am sending my html whole html document using socket.io event to nodejs server after processed my whole html document. But I am getting “RangeError: maximum call stack size exceeded”.

I have tried to send some small html content to my nodejs server and it's send very smoothly but when I send my whole html document then I am getting this error.

**This is working fine :**

```
 app.socket.emit('allSectionsData',{
                                    data:'<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><svg height="60" width="200">' +
                                    '<text x="0" y="15" fill="red" transform="rotate(30 20,40)">I love SVG</text>'+
                                'Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.</svg></body></html>'
                                });
```

But, When I am sending my whole document using this

```
var all_route_content=document.getElementById('All_outlet');

                            //setTimeout( function() {
                                app.socket.emit('allSectionsData',{
                                    data:all_route_content
                                });
                           //});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var all_route_content=document.getElementById('All_outlet').innerHTML;
```

You are sending complete DOM object with `document.getElementById('All_outlet')`

Comment: I did and getting the output but not proper. Actually what happens... It's taking only the outer content of my all inner div's. Not all